# MSBuild: building website using AspNetCompiler - adding references?

Tags: msbuild, reference

I'm attempting to build a ASP.NET website using MSBuild - specifically the AspNetCompiler tag. I know that, for my project, I need to add some references. Within Visual Studio I have several references, one is a project reference and the others are some DLLS (AjaxControlToolkit etc). I'm happy not referencing the project and referencing the DLL instead - however I just can't work out how to add a reference. I've looked up and down and this is what I've found so far:

```
<Target Name = "PrecompileWeb">
                <AspNetCompiler
                        VirtualPath = "DeployTemp" 
                        PhysicalPath = "D:\AutoBuild\CruiseControl\Projects\Websites\MyCompany\2.0.0\WorkingDirectory\VSS"
                        TargetPath = "D:\AutoBuild\CruiseControl\Projects\Websites\MyCompany\2.0.0\PreCompiled"
                        Force = "true"
                        Debug = "true"
            Updateable = "true"/>
        </Target>
```

Also - I've picked up this bit of code from around the web somewhere, which I thought might help:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="My.Web.DataEngine, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>D:\AutoBuild\CruiseControl\Projects\Components\My.Web.DataEngine\bin\Debug\My.Web.DataEngine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

What I want to do is add a attribute to the AspNetCompiler tag, something like:

```
References="@(Reference)"
```

but MSBuild isn't very happy about this.

I've been a bit stuck in not being able to find decent references on doing this anywhere: so I'd really apprechiate some pointers or reference material etc. (or just the answer!)

Thanks for you help.

-tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [aspnet_compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx) tool doesn't have a reference property.

Have you looked at using [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) ([2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx) version)?

Comment: Great - thanks for pointing me in the right direction, and out of a dead-end! I don't have enough rep to vote-up... but I shall do my best to remember for when I do!

Answer (score 0):

You can add references to assemblies used during the compilation of an ASP.NET application by adding to the `<assemblies>` element, under `<compilation>` if your web.config. For example:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.2" debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bfyb45k1(v=vs.100)